# Django - moderate users for admin approval

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, django-registration

I have created an app that allows users to create online products - basically a structured form fill with permissions.  I'm using Django's basic auth for sign up and login. When a user signs up I want the account to be approved by an admin before they can log in.  I know there are modules I can use to do this, but I wondered if there is something I can do to enable this without installing more stuff.

Here's the signup view:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

If it's not that simple and the best way is to use a module, which one is the best?  I've seen a couple but am not sure which one to use, if I have to use one.

Comment: If you really don't want to install an additional app, why not creating your new user with is_active = False ?

Comment: In simplistic terms that would work, but there would be no notification if a new account was created.  Again, if this isn't an easy thing to do I can use an additional app, just don't know which app is the best option.

Comment: as @Youngil Cho mentioned, simply use signals to keep your admin informed.

Comment: @normic I did that and it gave this error **'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'**

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install third party module, I think you should extend Django's user model.

This is an official Django documentation about this subject.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Design to record approve status on extended models. When the user logs in, it is likely that the approval status of the extended model is checked together with the Django login result, and the user is allowed to log in or not.

If you want to be notified about new users, you might want to use Django's "post_save" signal feature.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/

Comment: Thanks - I've already extended the user model so would probably have to edit that.  Of the third party apps, which are best to achieve this?